# How can I cluster plant biomass and grain weight for different plant varieties using Ward's method based clustering?

Tags: clustering, spss, euclidean, ward

I have plant biomass and grain weight data for different plant varieties which I now need to cluster. Do I need to define the number of clusters if using Ward's method and Squared Euclidean distance in SPSS? Also both of the variables are measured in same units so do I need to standardize this data?

Answer (score 0):

[Ward's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method) is a hierarchical clustering procedure, so number of cluster is not required to start (unlike k-means procedure, which requires number of cluster to be given beforehand).

Standardization is not required if the two dimensions are roughly on the same magnitude.

Comment: Thanks @Nuclear03020704, another doubt is whether there is any co-efficient associated to each cases defining how well they are classified in each cluster? If not how can we understand how good/bad are the clusters?